# How to replicate and copy the contents of watch window in Visual studio into a file (With the branching info being present in it)

Tags: visual-studio, file, visual-studio-2008, visual-studio-debugging, watch

I am debugging C++ using VS2008. The watch window used for debugging stores all the dynamic values in various objects, arrays, variables etc.

I want to copy the entire contents on this watch window into a file so that I can forward the debugging context to someone else.

If I just selct all (CTRL + A), and paste the contents in a file then i wont get the branching information (i.e info like an object might have various sub-objects in it).

Can anyone kindly let me know how to do this in VS2008.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to include the branching information, you have to manually expand each node. When you use <kbd>CTRL+A</kbd> and <kbd>CTRL+C</kbd>, the clipboard will contain only what is currently visible in the watch window.

Comment: S i did expand and copy but when i copied it's not showing the branches, although the contents of the branche sare there.