# How to get the quickwatch expression values in c#?

Tags: xamarin

How to get the value of quickwatch expression.Here is the image
[I am getting this data here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zlQ7W.png)

Want to store this ListView ItemSource in a Variable,so how to do this?

Comment: It is merely a ToString() call for each item in your enumerable... if the base class does not exposes the properties, you may get them using reflection. But you would have to write some debug code in your program for that. I'm also not sure whether your platform supports reflection or not.

Comment: If you mean copying and pasting the values from Visual Studio's interface, then this question was actually already asked here in SO: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10043626/how-to-replicate-and-copy-the-contents-of-watch-window-in-visual-studio-into-a-f

Comment: @Vidhya I always put expression in watch window so whenever I come near to my debugging point I just click refresh icon in watch and I am able to see variable value. Do you means something else.